# How to verify Alert contents using UIAutomation with tuneup.js

Tags: ios, uialertview, ui-automation, ios-ui-automation

I just started trying UIAutomation with tuneup.js. But I am unable to verify the Alert contents using following script.

```
 test("Login Screen: Test Alert", function(target, app)
 {
    UIATarget.onAlert = function onAlert(alert) 
    {
        var alert_title=alert.name();
        assertEquals("Test", alert_title);
        alert.cancelButton().tap();
     }
 }
 );
```

The above code returns result as PASS even though expected result “Test” does not match the actual result (“Check Password”). The alert.cancelButton().tap(); will work.
Can anyone help me on this issue? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you post your assertEquals code? That's not a standard function.

Comment: I tried it using UIALogger method also, but the problem is, code written inside the function onAlert(alert) is not getting executed.

Comment: One sec the formatting got all messed up I'm gonna just post as an answer!

Answer (score 0):

Your syntax is wrong is all!

```
UIATarget.onAlert = function onAlert(alert){}
```

Should be:

```
UIATarget.onAlert = function (alert){}
```

Comment: I tried your answer, but still it is not working with below code.              
UIATarget.onAlert = function (alert){
 var title = alert.name();
 UIALogger.logMessage("Alert with title " + title + " encountered!");
 return false;
}                                                  
Log Message:
target.frontMostApp().mainWindow().buttons()["LOGIN"].tap()    Debug
target.frontMostApp().alert().cancelButton().tap()             Debug

Comment: Hmm now that is interesting. When are you setting the `onAlert`? Make sure it's before your code that is creating the alert. 

Just so you know returning `false` will prompt the default alert handler after yours which may or may not be what you want.

Answer (score 0):

`UIATarget.onAlert` is a callback that is executed asynchronously with the rest of the test code.  Any exception that gets raised from `assertEquals` will not be caught by the test code.

You should probably work around this by setting a global variable from within the alert handler, and checking that variable from  your test code.